# Webpack 4 html partials resolve images in files

Tags: html, webpack, partials

I am new to webpack, I followed directions in this link https://github.com/hardikkaji/angularjs-es6-starter-kit

I am using webpack 4 with angular 1.7

I am not able to resolve images.

ERROR in ./node_modules/angular-datatables/demo/basic/overrideLoadingTpl.html
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './images/loading.gif' in '/home/user/workspace/webpack/angular-webpack/node_modules/angular-datatables/demo/basic'

My webpack.config.js is below

```
const config = {
    mode: devMode ? 'development' : 'production',
    entry: {
        'vendor': './frontend/vendor.module.js', //seperates all 3rd party plugins like ui-router, retstangualr etc 
        'app': './frontend/index.main.js' //main entry point for angular js
    },
    devtool: devMode ? 'source-map': 'none',
    output: {
        filename: elixirConfig.js.outputFolder + '/[name].[hash].bundle.js',
        //filename: 'libs/[name].[hash].bundle.js', //where to store the generated files all files will be generated inside a folder called libs
        //path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build')
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, elixirConfig.buildPath)
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /.js$/, //check for file that ends with .js extension
                exclude: /node_modules/, //do not check for files inside node_modules folder
                loader: ['ng-annotate-loader', 'babel-loader'],
                //presets: ['es2016'],
            },
            {
                test: /.(scss)$/, //check for files that end with scss
                use: [
                    devMode ? { loader: "style-loader" } : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    { loader: "css-loader", options: { minimize: true } },
                    { loader: "sass-loader" },
                ]
            },
            // for fixing of loading bootstrap icon files
            {
                test: /.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000',
                options: {
                    name: './fonts/[name].[ext]'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                    name: './fonts/[name].[ext]'
                }
            },
            { test: /.html$/, include: /node_modules/, loader: 'html-loader' },
        ]
    },
```